# Conditioning Format a Blank Cell based on the values from its Row and Column Header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My goal is to highlight a blank cell based on the date values from the row values and its column date value.

Like for example, if its "column date" >= "its start date", and "its column date" < "end date", the cell color will be yellow, else the cell color remains clear. (as shown in the below pic)[image: 1]

On Cell C2, I have tried applying AND(C$1 >= $A2, C$1 < $B2) and drag across the rest of the table, but the color of the cell value does not change.

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct.  However, with Conditional Formatting, always make sure that the range it applies to is correct.

If you had a cell other than `$C$2` selected when creating it, and then you copy/pasted formatting across the other cells, you won't get the formatting to work as you expected.

However, if you have `$C$2` active, and enter the formula `=AND(C$1>=$A2,C$1<$B2)`, then copy/paste formatting, it should work.

Alternatively, set the formula to be `=AND(C$1>=$A2,C$1<$B2)` and make sure the "Applies To" range is `=$C$2:$H$3`.

[image]

Edit: Just re-read, and you stated you did have `C2` selected when you made it. In that case, just make sure the "Applied To" range is correct. *Also* sometimes after changing the formatting, the formula *may* change to like `=And(C$123456>=$A123435,...`, so make sure the formula didn't change on accident too.

Comment: After correcting the "Applied To" range, the conditioning works. Thank you Bruce.

Comment: @Fxs7576 - Yeah, after a few cumulative hours wondering why my *oh so excellently written* Formula didn't work, I've come to realize that when expanding/changing a range for Conditional Formatting, Excel can tend to tweak it after you hit "apply", so I always double check the range after entering a CF.  Glad it's working!